# Unity: Code works great in editor but fails in build version (Windows 10 64 bit)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, editor

I'm getting a weird issue here: grid shows beautifully in the editor while running. However: it doesn't show in my build version

View the attached screenshot of the 2 builds below:

[Build version vs Editor version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQRBY.jpg)

Also i suppose it would be helpful to show you the script I wrote for it..:

```
 void GenerateGrid()
{
    Color gridColor = Color.cyan;
    Color borderColor = Color.black;
    Collider floorCollider = floor.GetComponent<Collider>();
    Vector3 foorSize = new Vector3(floorCollider.bounds.size.x, floorCollider.bounds.size.z);
    for (int x = 0; x < gridImage.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridImage.height; y++)
        {
            if (x < borderSize || x > gridImage.width - borderSize || y < borderSize || y > gridImage.height - borderSize)
            {
                gridImage.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(borderColor.r, borderColor.g, borderColor.b, 50));
            }
            else gridImage.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(gridColor.r, gridColor.g, gridColor.b, 50));
        }
        gridImage.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
        gridImage.Apply();
    }       
    floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture(1, gridImage);
    floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTextureScale(1, new Vector2(floorCollider.bounds.size.x, floorCollider.bounds.size.z));
    floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTextureOffset(1, new Vector2(.5f, .5f));
    Debug.Log(floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.GetTexture(1));

}
```

Comment: Are you using non standard shader? What shader and material are using for that plane?

Comment: No, it's a standard shader. The code doesn't modify the shader at all, just the texture.

Comment: What happens if you don't modify the texture? Can you post the screenshot of that in the Editor and build?

Comment: https://srv3.imgonline.com.ua/result_img/imgonline-com-ua-twotoone-pKn08lEZXvmqKON.jpg     That is the a screenshot without updated texture

Comment: Try `floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture("_MainTex", gridImage);`.  If you want to use `SetTexture(int nameID, Texture value);`  use `Shader.PropertyToID` to get `nameID`.

Comment: I figured it out right as you said that lol. I used floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetMainTexture() instead lol. I guess there was some conflicting textures going on there. Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem solved? If so, @Pluto put that as an answer to close this post.

Comment: Yes, problem is solved. @Pluto?

Comment: Ok. He has left an answer. You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it since that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture("_Mai‌​nTex", gridImage);`. 
 
 If you want to use `SetTexture(int nameID, Texture value);` you should use `Shader.PropertyToID` to get `nameID`.

> Each name of shader property (for example, _MainTex or _Color) is
>   assigned an unique integer number in Unity, that stays the same for
>   the whole game. The numbers will not be the same between different
>   runs of the game or between machines, so do not store them or send
>   them over network.